# Удалить required

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не получается удалить required

```js
function ok() {
  $('[id^="stol"]').removeProp("required", true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="stol[1]" required>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="stol[2]" required><br>
<a onclick="ok()">Удалить required</a>
```

Comment: `$('[id^="stol"]').removeAttr("required");`?

Comment: @Suvitruf спасибо, работает.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать `removeAttr`.

```js
function ok() {
  $('[id^="stol"]').removeAttr("required");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="stol[1]" required>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="stol[2]" required><br>
<a onclick="ok()">Удалить required</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

метод [`removeProp`](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) не рекомендуется использовать на нативных свойств. К тому же данный метод не принимает второй параметр. Вместо него можно воспользоваться методом [`prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) передав ему значение `false` вторым аргументом:

```js
function ok() {
  $('[id^="stol"]').prop("required", false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="console.log('submitted'); return false">
  <input type="radio" name="1" id="stol[1]" required>
  <input type="radio" name="1" id="stol[2]" required><br>
  <a onclick="ok()">Удалить required</a>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Либо если необходимо удалить именно атрибуты можно воспользоваться соответствующим методом [`removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```js
function ok() {
  $('[id^="stol"]').removeAttr("required");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="console.log('submitted'); return false">
  <input type="radio" name="1" id="stol[1]" required>
  <input type="radio" name="1" id="stol[2]" required><br>
  <a onclick="ok()">Удалить required</a>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```